# Error al crear db- Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "`id`" at position 152)

Tags: sql

verás, antes pude crear una db sin problemas y tenía la misma sintaxis que esta, pero esta no me deja crearla, dejo el código que inserto en el sql del phpmyadmin:

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `personal` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tipo_usuario` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `id_personal` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_tipo` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

Y este es el error:

Error

Análisis estático:

Se encontraron 2 errores durante el análisis.

```
Comienzo inesperado de declaración. (near "`id`" at position 152)
Tipo de declaración desconocida. (near "int" at position 157)
```

consulta SQL:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `personal` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL, `nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL ) CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tipo_usuario` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL, `tipo` varchar(50) NOT NULL ) CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL, `usuario` varchar(30) NOT NULL, `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `id_personal` int(11) NOT NULL, `id_tipo` int(11) NOT NULL )

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

## 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tipo_usuario` (

`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`tipo` ' en la linea 6

Comment: le faltarían los `;` al final de cada sentencia

Comment: LE añado el ; al final de cada sentencia pero no me deja igualmente

Comment: algo asi? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13bed4

Answer (score 0):

Tu error está en los punto y coma. Prueba así:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personal (
id int(11) NOT NULL,
nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tipo_usuario (
id int(11) NOT NULL,
tipo varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios (
id int(11) NOT NULL,
usuario varchar(30) NOT NULL,
password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
id_personal int(11) NOT NULL,
id_tipo int(11) NOT NULL
);
```